# Can someone help me with the code for receiving alerts when the first candle is greater/larger than second candle

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, tradingview-api

The first candle should be greater than the second one
Applicable to all timeframe

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a "1" when the newest candle is higher than the one before, a 0 if it's the same or lower.

You can replace "high" with "close" to get the candle close instead of the highest value.

```
study("Higher Candle Indicator")
plot(high > high[1] ? 1 : 0)
```